# Facebook App Access Token in Graph api call

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to make a public facebook video graph call in Android. But I am new to facebook graph and can't find how to replace user access token with my App access token.

```
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), //wanna replace with app access token
"/{video-id}",
null,
HttpMethod.GET,
new GraphRequest.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        /* handle the result */
    }
}
).executeAsync();
```

The same case for php is successfully done by below code.

```
try {
// Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
$response = $fb->get(
'/'.$_REQUEST["url"].'?fields=id,length',
'1234567890|-hjgstdusgdsgdsd***' // my app access token
);
  $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

echo $graphNode['id'];      
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo "error";         

} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo "error";         
}
```

Please help me, I am finding the whole day to get it. But still can't. Thanks in advance. I am new to facebook graph.

Comment: You should never expose your app access token in client-side code. Whatever you are actually trying to achieve here, you are on the wrong path.

Comment: @CBroe, Yes you are right. I really missed that point. Thank you.